# Google Fusion Tables Polygons to Points

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Fusion Table that contains some very small polygons over a very large area. I'd like to create an event that switches from polygons to points when the user zooms to a certain level. Currently, the points are only generated at the maximum-most zoom (the entire world). In [this example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/adv_fusiontables.html) the polygons turn to points when you zoom out by just one level and I'd like to do something similar. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering of polygons as points is not a selectable feature, it usually will happen when there are too many features(or when a feature may not be rendered properly).

What you can do: create another-geometry-column, where you store the desired points(e.g. the center of the polygon), then you'll be able to choose which column should be used to render the geometry.